# How can I add a XIB file to an iOS app that uses storyboards?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, storyboard, xib

If I shouldn't try to add a XIB file to an iOS app that already has storyboards, please let me know, but if there is a way to add XIB files or otherwise set Interface Builder constraints to elements, how can I do that?

Thanks,

Comment: You can add them no issue, just add a new Objective C class with NIB for UI

Comment: Thank you; please restate as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them no issue, just add a new Objective C class with NIB for UI

Answer (score 1):

You can add xib file on your when you have using the storyboard. That will not showing any warning or issue. But you can integrated xib file to any one of class if create xib file separately

[image]